# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Conexao

Tags: mysql, pdo

Estou com um problema que é um mistério para mim, em minha hospedagem na `locaweb` um site que estava funcionando normalmente ontem de manhã a tarde começou a me acusar um erro de conexão, ainda não entrei em contato com o suporte deles porque esse mesmo erro aconteceu a `1 mês` atrás e pedi um `restore` dos arquivos e tudo voltou a funcionar mas sem nenhuma explicação adicional da empresa.
Gostaria de poder entender o que está acontecendo, já pesquisei sobre o erro e vi que pode ser que o arquivo de conexão esteja sendo declarado 2 vezes, mas como disse, o site estava funcionando, por isso vim aqui expor a minha dúvida.

A minha página index tem essa configuração:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {    
  session_start();  
}

// Require da classe de conexão
include_once("_classes/conexao_pdo.class.php");
include_once("_classes/crud.dsc.class.php");

// Instancia Conexão PDO
$conexao = Conexao::getInstance();
$crud = Crud::getInstance($conexao);
```

O chamada conexao_pdo.class.php está assim:

```
include_once('_connections/config_db.php');

class Conexao {
    /*
     * Atributo estático para instância do PDO  
     */

    private static $pdo;

    /*
     * Escondendo o construtor da classe  
     */

    private function __construct() {

    }

    /*
     * Método estático para retornar uma conexão válida  
     * Verifica se já existe uma instância da conexão, caso não, configura uma nova conexão  
     */

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$pdo)) {
            try {
                $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8', PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE);
                self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . HOST . "; dbname=" . DBNAME . "; charset=" . CHARSET . ";", USER, PASSWORD, $opcoes);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                print "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$pdo;
    }

}
```

A minha página `config_db.php` está assim:

```
define('HOST', 'meu hosts'); 
define('USER', 'usuario'); 
define('PASSWORD', 'senha'); 
define('DBNAME', 'banco');
define('TYPEDB', 'mysql'); 
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

A página `crud.dsc.class.php` está assim:

```
class Crud {

    // Atributo para guardar uma conexão PDO   
    private $pdo = null;
    // Atributo estático que contém uma instância da própria classe   
    private static $crud = null;

    /*
     * Método privado construtor da classe    
     * @param $conexao = Conexão PDO configurada   
     * @param $tabela = Nome da tabela    
     */

    private function __construct($conexao) {

        if (!empty($conexao)):
            $this->pdo = $conexao;
        else:
            echo "Conexão inexistente!";
            exit();
        endif;

    }

    /*
     * Método público estático que retorna uma instância da classe Crud    
     * @param $conexao = Conexão PDO configurada   
     * @param $tabela = Nome da tabela   
     * @return Atributo contendo instância da classe Crud   
     */

    public static function getInstance($conexao) {

        // Verifica se existe uma instância da classe   
        if (!isset(self::$crud)):
            try {
                self::$crud = new Crud($conexao);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "Erro " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        endif;

        return self::$crud;
    }

    /*
     * Método privado para construção da instrução SQL de INSERT   
     * @param $arrayDados = Array de dados contendo colunas e valores   
     * @return String contendo instrução SQL   
     */

    private function buildInsert($tabela, $arrayDados) {

        // Inicializa variáveis   
        $sql = "";
        $campos = "";
        $valores = "";

        // Loop para montar a instrução com os campos e valores   
        foreach ($arrayDados as $chave => $valor):
            $campos .= $chave . ', ';
            $valores .= '?, ';
        endforeach;

        // Retira vírgula do final da string   
        $campos = (substr($campos, -2) == ', ') ? trim(substr($campos, 0, (strlen($campos) - 2))) : $campos;

        // Retira vírgula do final da string   
        $valores = (substr($valores, -2) == ', ') ? trim(substr($valores, 0, (strlen($valores) - 2))) : $valores;

        // Concatena todas as variáveis e finaliza a instrução   
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO " . $tabela . " (" . $campos . ")VALUES(" . $valores . ")";

        // Retorna string com instrução SQL   
        return trim($sql);
    }

    /*
     * Método privado para construção da instrução SQL de UPDATE   
     * @param $arrayDados = Array de dados contendo colunas, operadores e valores   
     * @param $arrayCondicao = Array de dados contendo colunas e valores para condição WHERE   
     * @return String contendo instrução SQL   
     */

    private function buildUpdate($tabela, $arrayDados, $arrayCondicao) {

        // Inicializa variáveis   
        $sql = "";
        $valCampos = "";
        $valCondicao = "";

        // Loop para montar a instrução com os campos e valores   
        foreach ($arrayDados as $chave => $valor):
            $valCampos .= $chave . '=?, ';
        endforeach;

        // Loop para montar a condição WHERE   
        foreach ($arrayCondicao as $chave => $valor):
            $valCondicao .= $chave . '? AND ';
        endforeach;

        // Retira vírgula do final da string   
        $valCampos = (substr($valCampos, -2) == ', ') ? trim(substr($valCampos, 0, (strlen($valCampos) - 2))) : $valCampos;

        // Retira vírgula do final da string   
        $valCondicao = (substr($valCondicao, -4) == 'AND ') ? trim(substr($valCondicao, 0, (strlen($valCondicao) - 4))) : $valCondicao;

        // Concatena todas as variáveis e finaliza a instrução   
        $sql .= "UPDATE " . $tabela . " SET " . $valCampos . " WHERE " . $valCondicao;

        // Retorna string com instrução SQL   
        return trim($sql);
    }

    /*
     * Método privado para construção da instrução SQL de DELETE   
     * @param $arrayCondicao = Array de dados contendo colunas, operadores e valores para condição WHERE   
     * @return String contendo instrução SQL   
     */

    private function buildDelete($tabela, $arrayCondicao) {

        // Inicializa variáveis   
        $sql = "";
        $valCampos = "";

        // Loop para montar a instrução com os campos e valores   
        foreach ($arrayCondicao as $chave => $valor):
            $valCampos .= $chave . '? AND ';
        endforeach;

        // Retira a palavra AND do final da string   
        $valCampos = (substr($valCampos, -4) == 'AND ') ? trim(substr($valCampos, 0, (strlen($valCampos) - 4))) : $valCampos;

        // Concatena todas as variáveis e finaliza a instrução   
        $sql .= "DELETE FROM " . $tabela . " WHERE " . $valCampos;

        // Retorna string com instrução SQL   
        return trim($sql);
    }

    /*
     * Método público para inserir os dados na tabela   
     * @param $arrayDados = Array de dados contendo colunas e valores   
     * @return Retorna resultado booleano da instrução SQL   
     */

    public function insert($tabela, $arrayDados) {
        try {

            // Atribui a instrução SQL construida no método   
            $sql = $this->buildInsert($tabela, $arrayDados);

            // Passa a instrução para o PDO   
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

            // Loop para passar os dados como parâmetro   
            $cont = 1;
            foreach ($arrayDados as $valor):
                $stm->bindValue($cont, $valor);
                $cont++;
            endforeach;

            // Executa a instrução SQL e captura o retorno   
            $retorno = $stm->execute();

            return $retorno;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Método público para atualizar os dados na tabela   
     * @param $arrayDados = Array de dados contendo colunas e valores   
     * @param $arrayCondicao = Array de dados contendo colunas e valores para condição WHERE - Exemplo array('$id='=>1)   
     * @return Retorna resultado booleano da instrução SQL   
     */

    public function update($tabela, $arrayDados, $arrayCondicao) {
        try {

            // Atribui a instrução SQL construida no método   
            $sql = $this->buildUpdate($tabela, $arrayDados, $arrayCondicao);

            // Passa a instrução para o PDO   
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

            // Loop para passar os dados como parâmetro   
            $cont = 1;
            foreach ($arrayDados as $valor):
                $stm->bindValue($cont, $valor);
                $cont++;
            endforeach;

            // Loop para passar os dados como parâmetro cláusula WHERE   
            foreach ($arrayCondicao as $valor):
                $stm->bindValue($cont, $valor);
                $cont++;
            endforeach;

            // Executa a instrução SQL e captura o retorno   
            $retorno = $stm->execute();

            return $retorno;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Método público para excluir os dados na tabela   
     * @param $arrayCondicao = Array de dados contendo colunas e valores para condição WHERE - Exemplo array('$id='=>1)   
     * @return Retorna resultado booleano da instrução SQL   
     */

    public function delete($tabela, $arrayCondicao) {
        try {

            // Atribui a instrução SQL construida no método   
            $sql = $this->buildDelete($tabela, $arrayCondicao);

            // Passa a instrução para o PDO   
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

            // Loop para passar os dados como parâmetro cláusula WHERE   
            $cont = 1;
            foreach ($arrayCondicao as $valor):
                $stm->bindValue($cont, $valor);
                $cont++;
            endforeach;

            // Executa a instrução SQL e captura o retorno   
            $retorno = $stm->execute();

            return $retorno;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Método genérico para executar instruções de consulta independente do nome da tabela passada no _construct  
     * @param $sql = Instrução SQL inteira contendo, nome das tabelas envolvidas, JOINS, WHERE, ORDER BY, GROUP BY e LIMIT  
     * @param $arrayParam = Array contendo somente os parâmetros necessários para clásula WHERE  
     * @param $fetchAll  = Valor booleano com valor default TRUE indicando que serão retornadas várias linhas, FALSE retorna apenas a primeira linha  
     * @return Retorna array de dados da consulta em forma de objetos  
     */

    public function getSQLGeneric($sql, $arrayParams = null, $fetchAll = TRUE) {
        try {

            // Passa a instrução para o PDO   
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

            // Verifica se existem condições para carregar os parâmetros    
            if (!empty($arrayParams)):

                // Loop para passar os dados como parâmetro cláusula WHERE   
                $cont = 1;
                foreach ($arrayParams as $valor):
                    $stm->bindValue($cont, $valor);
                    $cont++;
                endforeach;

            endif;

            // Executa a instrução SQL    
            $stm->execute();

            // Verifica se é necessário retornar várias linhas  
            if ($fetchAll):
                $dados = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            else:
                $dados = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            endif;

            return $dados;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar a entender, agradeço.

O erro pode ser visto aqui:
[Erro ao acessar o site](http://ciposuspensoes.com.br/)

Lembrei de um fato importante que tinha passado, eu estava com um erro que deixava um espaço em branco no topo da minha página e me mostrava esse caracter: &#65279, ai rodei esse script que consegui aqui mesmo:

```html
<?php 
// Tell me the root folder path.
// You can also try this one
// $HOME = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
// Or this
// dirname(__FILE__)
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$HOME = dirname(__FILE__);

// Is this a Windows host ? If it is, change this line to $WIN = 1;
$WIN = 0;

// That's all I need
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>UTF8 BOM FINDER and REMOVER</title>
<style>
body { font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: #FFF; color: #000; }
.FOUND { color: #F30; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$BOMBED = array();
RecursiveFolder($HOME);
echo '<h2>These files had UTF8 BOM, but i cleaned them:</h2><p class="FOUND">';
foreach ($BOMBED as $utf) { echo $utf ."<br />\n"; }
echo '</p>';

// Recursive finder
function RecursiveFolder($sHOME) {
  global $BOMBED, $WIN;

  $win32 = ($WIN == 1) ? "\\" : "/";

  $folder = dir($sHOME);

  $foundfolders = array();
  while ($file = $folder->read()) {
    if($file != "." and $file != "..") {
      if(filetype($sHOME . $win32 . $file) == "dir"){
        $foundfolders[count($foundfolders)] = $sHOME . $win32 . $file;
      } else {
        $content = file_get_contents($sHOME . $win32 . $file);
        $BOM = SearchBOM($content);
        if ($BOM) {
          $BOMBED[count($BOMBED)] = $sHOME . $win32 . $file;

          // Remove first three chars from the file
          $content = substr($content,3);
          // Write to file 
          file_put_contents($sHOME . $win32 . $file, $content);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  $folder->close();

  if(count($foundfolders) > 0) {
    foreach ($foundfolders as $folder) {
      RecursiveFolder($folder, $win32);
    }
  }
}

// Searching for BOM in files
function SearchBOM($string) { 
    if(substr($string,0,3) == pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)) return true;
    return false; 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

E depois disso, essa mensagem de erro de redeclaração da classe começou a surgir.

Comment: Quando você escreveu **restore** você estava pensando nesse comando `mysql -u root -p seu-database < seu-arquivo-dump`? Onde `seu-database` é o arquivo contendo o banco de dados e `seu-arquivo-dump` é o backup?

Comment: Olá @AugustoVasques, solicitei um restore das páginas pela locaweb, o restore foi feito a aplicação voltou a funcionar e depois começou a acusar esse erro, não entendi bem a sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber como é que foi feito o processo de `restore` no prompt. Mas parece que foi sua equipe de suporte quem executou a ação.

Comment: Em qual página o erro é reportado? É na própria index? Ele dá o número da linha?

Comment: Olá @HiagoSouza, dá erro já na index, coloquei o link de acesso do site na pergunta.

Comment: Basicamente o erro diz que a classe é definida duas ou mais vezes, sempre diz o nome do arquivo ou pode ser uma configuração do apache que adiciona esse arquivo de conexão a cada requisiçã, veja por `auto prepend`.

Comment: só para teste comente essa linha 15 e me fale o resultado.

Comment: Olá @Bulfaitelo, me perdoe pela demora, estava enfemo, mas comentando a parte solicitada não é possível, postei a classe na  pergunta e ela começa no class Conexao {